# Is there a way to check for shift held down THEN control held down for each input?

Tags: c++, windows, keyboard, getch

I'm trying to use _getch to get keyboard strokes for incrementing money in a game. If I want the money to be incremented faster, in 10's while shift is held down and 100's control is held down what would be the best way to do that? If I just check for shifts it's easy enough, but if I want to check for a shift then a control afterwards it won't work.

For instance checking to increment by 1 or 10 I'd do something like this

```
key = _getch();
if (key == 224)
{
    key = _getch();
    if (key == 75) // left arrow
    {
        if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_SHIFT)
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) // go left 10 times
                    left();
        else
            left();
    }
}
```

If I add an else if for control for 100's it will NOT work. Most likely because running the GetAsyncKeyState fucntion again makes it not read the key state properly.

```
else if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_CONTROL)
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) // go left 100 times
        left();
```

Any possible workaround? Thanks!

Comment: May be if you can tell me your complete use case then programmers here can help you in a better way than using GetAsyncKeyState().

Comment: People seem to misunderstanding what I am going for. I want the program to increment a counter by 1 with no modifier, by 10's if shift is held, and by 100's if control is held. No keyboard cominbaitons just a way to do a if, else if, and else check for shift, control, and neither. Does that make sense?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Turns out control prevent the console from "flushing". So, it was just a problem with control itself causing the error, I decided to use while-shift held for 10's and while-tab held for 100's. If there is a way to use alt, which I don't think there is, I'd use that. This is just a typical case of me being stupid and taking like 3 hours to realize it was the keybind interacting with the cmd prompt causing the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Try the below code to make sure you can use multiple keys together. There is a limitation by the hardware to recognize simultaneous multiple key press so keep this in your mind.

Main calling function,

```
while(!keydown(VK_LCONTROL))
{
    if(keydown(VK_LCONTROL) && keydown(VK_NUMPAD1) && keydown(VK_UP))
    {
        cout << "combo pressed!" << endl;
    }
    Sleep(10);
}
```

Function keydown,

```
BOOL keydown(int key)
{
    return (GetAsyncKeyState(key) & 0x8000) != 0;
}
```

(GetAsyncKeyState(key) & 0x8000) != 0; We are only interested in the 15th bit so check this one. For further details check the respective bit's info.

Try combination of keys like control+numberpad1+Up for 1's increment, control+numberpad2+Up for 10's increment etc.

Comment: I'm sorry if I worded my question a little weird. I didn't want the program to check for multiple inputs at once. I just want two seperate if checks one for shift key held one for incrementing by 10's and if that check fails do one for control where it'd increment by 100's, and finally an else where it'd just increment by 1's only.

Answer (score 0):

How about "if(GetAsyncKeyState(VK_SHIFT) && GetAsyncKeyState(VK_CONTROL))"? You can not use one GAKS call to check multiple keys.

Comment: I'm sorry if I worded my question a little weird, I want two seperate if checks one for shift key held one for incrementing by 10's and if that check fails do one for control where it'd increment by 100's, and finally an else where it'd just increment by 1's only.